# Sandbox for Posting Questions

Tags: support, api, sandbox

Is there any Sandbox for posting question? I beleive I can only post comment or answers in the existing Sandboxes (Formatting and API sandbox), Do I need to Create a new question in order to test question add API?Could anybody help on this?

Comment: I agree, that's a great idea.